# Download and apply images on run time in android app

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

i am developing an android app, and i want user to download the file(images) after installation and the store them on sd card ,then aply them in my app ,there will be a default app before user download the images and the these images will be applied. I know little bit about DownloadManager class but don't know how to store them and retrieving them on run time.
any tutorial or any sample source code.. ??

Answer (score 0):

I personally have never used the download manager, so I cannot say anything on that. Your best bet would probably be to check for the files' existances using `File.exists()` and downloading / applying these images in an `AsyncTask<Param, Progress, Result>` or thread. `AsyncTask` is typically the way people go.

Whichever route you take, be wary of what is happening in the background and what is happening on the main thread. UI updates **must** happen on the main thread. All network code **must** happen in the background. Any deviation from that will crash.